# .ascx user control button_click is not firing Sitefinity C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, sitefinity, buttonclick

I have come across this weird problem where my button click event is not firing. I have tried almost all the possiblities but still no luck. googling for couple of hours now but still no help. Some ppl experienced exactly the same problem on different forums but no specific answer. I tried the button_click event and also tried registring an event handler, none of them work.
In my scenario I have a sitefinity5 custom module where I am showing employee information along with employee data. on employee picture click i am displaying a JQUERY dialog where i have this button. When application load, it fires the page_load of code behind file and also when i click on employee picture at first, it fires the page_load but dont fire button_click ever. Any subsequent click on picture dont even fire the Page_Load.
Anyone's help will really really be appreciated. Following is my code snippet.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="SitefinityWebApp.SfCtrlPresentation.OpenAccessDataProvider_a4a794260c0b4440b466f75d11146db8" Codebehind="OpenAccessDataProvider,a4a794260c0b4440b466f75d11146db8.ascx.cs" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.PublicControls.BrowseAndEdit" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.ContentUI" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Comments" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI.Fields" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="sf" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
<%--<%@ Register TagPrefix="jq" Assembly="Telerik.Sitefinity" Namespace="Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.UI" %>--%>

<telerik:RadListView ID="dynamicContentListView" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemsContainer" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul class="sfitemsList sfitemsListTitleDateTmb">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemsContainer" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
      <li class="sfitem sfClearfix">
            <h2 class="sfitemTitle">
                <sf:DetailsViewHyperLink ID="DetailsViewHyperLink" TextDataField="Title" runat="server" />
            </h2>
           <sf:AssetsField ID="AssetsField1" runat="server" DataFieldName="Picture" />
           <sf:SitefinityLabel ID="SitefinityLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Designation")%>'  WrapperTagName="div" HideIfNoText="true" CssClass="sfitemShortTxt" />           
          <sf:SitefinityLabel ID="SitefinityLabel2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CompanyName")%>' WrapperTagName="div" HideIfNoText="true" CssClass="sfitemShortTxt" />
          <sf:AssetsField ID="AssetsField2" runat="server" DataFieldName="Documents"/>
      </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListView>

<sf:Pager id="pager" runat="server"></sf:Pager>

<sf:ResourceLinks ID="resourcesLinks" runat="server">
    <sf:ResourceFile JavaScriptLibrary="JQuery" />
</sf:ResourceLinks>


<div class="dialogTest"> <br />
<br />
Please enter your email address: <input type="text" name="emailAddress" style="width: 300px;" /><br />
<br />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br/>
<asp:LinkButton Runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" /> <br/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CausesValidation="False" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />

<%--<button name="btnSubmit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" >Submit</button>--%>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j(".sfClearfix .sfimageWrp img").click(function () {
        $j(".dialogTest").addClass("open");
        //return $j(this).attr("src");
    });
});
</script>


//.cs file
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Events;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Events.Model;

namespace SitefinityWebApp.SfCtrlPresentation
{
    public partial class OpenAccessDataProvider_a4a794260c0b4440b466f75d11146db8 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        //protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    base.OnLoad(e);
        //}

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            { 
                btnSubmit.Click+= new EventHandler(btnSubmit_Click);
            }
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this for a user control on a public front end page? go into the page properties (in the Action menu under the Pages list in the admin) and make sure to check the box to enable ViewState

By default, Sitefinity disables viewstate to improve performance.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: yes this dialog is for public front end. I have enabled the ViewState but still no difference

Comment: can you verify using something like firebug or chrome developer tools that there are no javascript errors being thrown?

Comment: also, I noticed this is a widget template you're mapping with the guid, have you verified that the widget is indeed loading this template?

Comment: Yes Josh, I have checked with firebug and there is no javascript errors. there is no problem with the widget either, it is loading the template. I am also unable to figure out why the page_load fires only at first time button_click. Any subsequent clicks dont even fire the page_load.